# How to view GoogleAnalyticsTracker.trackPageView's sent data?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to add GoogleAnalytics calls to my Android app. I created account in GoogleAnalytics, downloaded libraries, instanciated GoogleAnalyticsTracker class, wrote calls like:

```
tracker.trackPageView(myData);
```

across the app.
My question: as Google analytics user, how can I view all analytics data? I want to examine that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I used trackPageView method, all data I sent was stored in Content -> Site content -> Pages in Google Analytics. This is list of visited pages.

Answer (score 4):

Several options available to you:

-Google Analytics offers real-time tracking.  Easiest thing to do would be to have Analytics open in a window on your machine, and watch for hits as you use your application.

-Also, by calling

```
tracker.setDebug(true);
```

You can enter debug mode, which means all requests to GA are sent to the Android log, which you can view using DDMS (either stand-alone or as part of the eclipse plugin).  This is probably the option you want.  In this case you probably also want to call

```
tracker.setDryRun(true);
```

which will prevent the data from actually being sent to GA servers, so you can experiment all you want without messing up your production stats.  Of course, be sure to remove this line before you ship :)

Comment: These methods are ok, but I want to view data on actual website. When I enter analytics website and login, can I view all the data my app sent? How to do it?

Comment: View the getting started page here:  https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1006228&answer=1009694
Once you've got it set up, there will be a code associated with the property you want to track.  It'll look like "UA-XXXXXX-X".  Initialize the Android tracker with that UA code.  Then you'll be able to view all the data from inside google analytics.